# Como pegar título e conteúdo em outra página?

Tags: php, wordpress

Gostaria de saber se é possível pegar o título e o conteúdo de uma página criada em outra página.

Por exemplo; eu criei um página chamada `Home` e criei também um template para essa página, e fiz o mesmo para o uma página chamada `quem somos`.

Na página `home` eu gostaria de mostrar uma breve descrição do conteúdo da página `quem somos`.

Isso é possível?

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito mas você quer exibir uma preview do conteúdo de uma página ? Você terá que fazer na mão mesmo, pois não existe um modo pelo qual você consegue exibir uma 'prévia' da sua página. Mas pesquise sobre o uso dos 'Iframes', com eles você consegue exibir uma página dentro dele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode, no template da página **"home"**, criar um *loop* específico buscando as informações da página **"quem somos"**. Algo desse tipo

```
$query = new WP_Query(array( 'pagename' => 'quem-somos' ));

if($query->have_posts()){
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();

        $titulo = the_title();
        $conteudo = the_content();

        # code....
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // restaurando a global $post
```

deve atender a sua necessidade. Alguns pontos que merecem atenção:

1. Uma página, no WP, é também um tipo de *post*. Por isso, o *loop* funciona. Como só existe uma página com o nome **"quem somos"**, só haverá um retorno.
2. O parâmetro do construtor da *WP_Query* (você pode ver todos os vários parâmetros [aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)) é um *array* associativo, e a chave **"pagename"** corresponde, obrigatoriamente, ao *slug* da página. Veja, o *slug*, não o nome. Você pode ler mais sobre *slugs* [aqui](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/post-slug/).